# resource level authorisation in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want finer level of authorisation and i am using WSO2 API Manager to secure my API's.
I have books and authors in my application and there is an API  for editing the book.Editing of the book should only be done by its author.How can restrict this via WSO2? 
my book editing may look like /api/book/{bookname} . This book should be edited by its author only. 
I am not sure how to do this by APIM. May  be generate each scope for each book and programatically associate this to the author OR so. Still how can I give scope to API based on the query para {bookname}Is there some kind of query parameter associated scope ?
Please throw some light on solutions for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Scopes can be associated with roles only. They can't be associated with users.

But you should be able to get what you want using custom mediation sequences. See [docs here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+Mediation+Extensions).

See [this blog post](http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2016/08/wso2-api-manager-how-to-retrieve.html) to get to know what data you can read within custom sequences.

You can keep a map between book to author somewhere and use that information in a custom sequence. For example, this map can be exposed as an external service or a static map in a class mediator.

Comment: Sorry,,Can you please explain more on what is A Meditation sequence?
How can i use this to authorize the API call?

Comment: With mediation sequences you can write any mediation logic. You can check username and requested resource for the extra authorization.

Comment: How can I write this extra authorisation in wso2?Is there any component which I should override or include in addition?

Comment: I think i got some understanding..A few questions
1)   Using a custom mediation sequence , i can check user name and extra validate authorization...How to prevent/block if the authorization fails? 
2)    Where to keep the book to author information? If its in database , can i call the database queries from this mediation sequence.. 
3)    Is this not the purpose of a CustomAPIAuthenticationHandler rather than a mediator?

Thank You

Comment: 1) You can send a response back to client with http 403 or something. 
2) yes you can. or you can call any external services. 
3) You can do it either way.

Comment: Regarding (3) point ; isn't a  custom handler necessary in this case? Since i have to hit DB and get the author for the book , verify if the incoming token is of the same author ... How to do all this in mediation sequence?
Is there a java based mediation sequence to write this logic?I am seeing mainly XML based mediation sequence...Is it possible to achieve this by XML based mediation ?